# Only using items from one list once in nested list comprehension

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nested, list-comprehension

I'm trying to use list comprehension to generate a new list that consists of a letter taken from a list1 directly followed (after a colon) by the words from list2 that start with that particular letter. I managed to code this using nested for loops as following:

```
list1=["A","B"]
list2=["Apple","Banana","Balloon","Boxer","Crayons","Elephant"]

newlist=[]
for i in list1:
    newlist.append(i+":")
    for j in list2:
        if j[0]==i:
            newlist[-1]+=j+","
```

resulting in the intended result: `['A:Apple,', 'B:Banana,Balloon,Boxer,']`

Trying the same using list comprehension, I came up with the following:

```
list1=["A","B"]
list2=["Apple","Banana","Balloon","Boxer","Crayons","Elephant"]

newlist=[i+":"+j+"," for i in list1 for j in list2 if i==j[0]]
```

resulting in: `['A:Apple,', 'B:Banana,', 'B:Balloon,', 'B:Boxer,']`

In which each time a word with that starting letter is found, a new item is created in `newlist`, while my intention is to have one item per letter.

Is there a way to edit the list comprehension code in order to obtain the same result as using the nested for loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to remove the second `for` loop and replace it with a `','.join(matching_words)` call where you use `j` now in the string concatenation now:

```
newlist = ['{}:{}'.format(l, ','.join([w for w in list2 if w[0] == l])) for l in list1]
```

This isn't very efficient; you loop over *all* the words in `list2` for each letter. To do this efficiently, you would be better of to preprocess the lists into a dictionary:

```
list2_map = {}
for word in list2:
    list2_map.setdefault(word[0], []).append(word)

newlist = ['{}:{}'.format(l, ','.join(list2_map.get(l, []))) for l in list1]
```

The first loop builds a dictionary mapping initial letter to a list of words, so that you can directly use those lists instead of using a nested list comprehension.

Demo:

```
>>> list1 = ['A', 'B']
>>> list2 = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Balloon', 'Boxer', 'Crayons', 'Elephant']
>>> list2_map = {}
>>> for word in list2:
...     list2_map.setdefault(word[0], []).append(word)
...
>>> ['{}:{}'.format(l, ','.join(list2_map.get(l, []))) for l in list1]
['A:Apple', 'B:Banana,Balloon,Boxer']
```

The above algorithm loops twice through all of `list2`, and once through `list1`, making this a O(N) linear algorithm (adding a single word to `list2` or a single letter to `list1` increases the amount of time with a constant amount). Your version loops over `list2` once for every letter in `list1`, making it a O(NM) algorithm, creating increasing the amount of time it takes exponentially whenever you add a letter or word.

To put that into numbers, if you expanded `list1` to cover all 26 ASCII uppercase letters and expanded `list2` to contain 1000 words, your approach (scanning all of `list2` for words with a given letter) would make 26000 steps. My version, including pre-building the map, takes only 2026 steps. With `list2` containing 1 million words, your version has to make 26 million steps, mine 2 million and 26.

Answer (score 2):

```
list1=["A","B"]
list2=["Apple","Banana","Balloon","Boxer","Crayons","Elephant"]

res = [l1 + ':' + ','.join(l2 for l2 in list2 if l2.startswith(l1)) for l1 in list1]
print(res)

# ['A:Apple', 'B:Banana,Balloon,Boxer']
```

But it seems to be complicated to read, so I would advice to use nested loops. You can create generator for more readability (if you think this version is more readable):

```
def f(list1, list2):
    for l1 in list1:
        val = ','.join(l2 for l2 in list2 if l2.startswith(l1))
        yield l1 + ':' + val

print(list(f(list1, list2)))

# ['A:Apple', 'B:Banana,Balloon,Boxer']
```

Comment: The generator doesn't make this any more efficient; it'll be slightly *slower* in terms of execution, and because you are calling `list()` on the generator you undo any memory efficiency there may have been.

Comment: Moreover, your version still suffers from O(NM) exponential complexity. With 26 letters and 1000 words your version takes 26000 steps, mine takes 2026.

Comment: "The generator doesn't make this any more efficient", in case he need ready list - yes. In case he will iterate through values - no. But efficiency is not main point: I think this solution is more readable then others.

Comment: @germn, using join on a generator means a list will be created regardless  so there is no advantage

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: `f` is the generator in question here (it uses `yield`). I haven't even started about the generator expression used in the `str.join()` :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I updated answer to be more accurate.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, ah ok, the complexity is the bigger issue  but it still amazes how many people don't realise that str.join with a generator is not actually  memory efficient.

Comment: @MartijnPieters "I haven't even started about the generator expression used in the str.join()" - I understand it's not more efficient then list. But there's also no reason to use list instead of generator inside join, am I right?

Comment: @germn: `str.join()` is an exception here, using a list comprehension is faster than a generator expression: [list comprehension without \[ \], Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024)